# SPARQL query returns nothing

Tags: sparql

I just started writing SPARQL queries. I created an ontology of countries, cities, counties and towns. I wanted to run a query that returns the name of a town and the town's population, but instead my query returns blank entries in the tables for town and population.

This is the query I wrote:

```
PREFIX countries-and-cities: <http://www.semanticweb.org/xxxxxxx/ontologies/2022/11/countries-and-cities#>

SELECT ?Town ?Population 
    WHERE { ?Town countries-and-cities:Population ?Population. }
```

Comment: Quite difficult to answer without more details of the ontology and data ingested. Can you provide any further context? Have you considered making use of dbpedia for geographical information in rdf format rather than creating your own?

Comment: Given that the query is very simple, the only issue here can be that the predicate used is wrong, i.e. it doesn't match the data. Are you sure that the property for population is a) using the same namespace you used in the prefix declaration and b) it's called "Population" and not "population" or "hasPopulation" or ....

Comment: @UninformedUser I declared the predicate exactly as it appears when in the ontology. The predicate "Population" is a data property. I entered the values for "Population" as a data property assertion for each Town.

Comment: @HES,  I am not familiar with dbpedia, but let me try and see if it works out then I tell you

Comment: if the data really matches the predicate, then the result can't be empty. Which triple store do you use? Or directly in Protege? Not that it matters. Also, again please double-check the prefix declaration. For us, you could also post a subset of the data in RDF syntax, especially the header would be interesting

Comment: I noticed a discrepancy in one of my individual entities, which I corrected, but it still wouldn't work. So I did this instead: PREFIX countries-and-cities: <http://www.semanticweb.org/xxxxxxx/ontologies/2022/11/countries-and-cities#>
SELECT *
WHERE {?Town <http://www.semanticweb.org/xxxxxx/ontologies/2022/11/untitled-ontology-9#Population> ?Population.}

Comment: Now it works fine if I use the IRI instead of aliases.

Comment: then you prefix declaration was wrong. using the prefix resolves to the full IRI, it doesn't matter if I write `PREFIX foo: <https://ex.org/> SELECT { ex:bar ?p ?o }` or `SELECT { <https://ex.org/bar> ?p ?o }`

Comment: @UninformedUser How should I declare predicates? I see that in `SELECT { ex:bar ?p ?o }` you used the `ex` from `<https://ex.org/>`.  In my prefix, I have `http://www.semanticweb.org/xxxxxxx/ontologies/2022/11/countries-and-cities#` but some of the individuals have the IRI `http://www.semanticweb.org/xxxxxxx/ontologies/2022/11/untitled-ontology-9#`. Could this be the reason why my aliases aren't working?

Comment: you only have to declare those prefix(es) that comprise namespaces of schema entities like the property you want to use in the query. For the resultset it doesn't matter if there are then other entities from different namespace.